# Is it possible to manually instantiate component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-components

In angular 2, is it possible to manually instantiate a component A, then pass it around and render in the template of component B?

Comment: Welcome to SO please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be helping you to raise your question content quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's supported. You need a `ViewComponentRef` that can for example be acquired by injecting it to the constructor or using a `@ViewChild('targetname')` query and a `ComponentResolver` that also can be injected.

This code example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325468/217408 allows for example to add components dynamically with `*ngFor`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dcl-wrapper',
  template: `<div #target></div>`
})
export class DclWrapper {
  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  @Input() type;
  cmpRef:ComponentRef;
  private isViewInitialized:boolean = false;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

  updateComponent() {
    if(!this.isViewInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
   this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.type).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.updateComponent();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isViewInitialized = true;
    this.updateComponent();  
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: this example doesnt allow for instantiating a component with data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The more complete example in the linked answer shows how to pass data in and out.