# How to instantiate and render Angular2 components?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to learn angular2 (and Typescript) and having followed the quick start guide and a few unofficial tutorials I've made progress to have a simple application with some components.

I understand the process of binding model data to the DOM element using the bracketed notation in my templates: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`

What I'm struggling to understand is how I could dynamically instantiate a new component from within my Typscript code, and then render that in the DOM.

If I import a component to my file and instantiate a new one, that will trigger the component's constructor in the model. Does Angular2 then allow me to  render this, or append a component to another component or queried div element?

```
import {ListComponent} from './list.component';
...
export class MainAppComponent {

    buttonClicked(){
        // I'm creating a new list component. What is the proper way to render it within this MainAppComponent?
        this.list = new ListComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: no problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063455/is-it-possible-to-manually-instantiate-component-in-angular-2   

and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to many concepts from [Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/). In Angular you do not instantiate by yourself the components and add them to the DOM, Angular takes care of everything, the pattern is :

- Having a parent component which has a template
- Having a child component which has a selector
- You import and add the child component selector inside the parent
  component template
- The child component is rendered inside the parent component

There are too many things for learning from questioning here, you need to follow the [Angular2 tutorial HERE](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), and then the [Angular2 basics docs HERE](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/)

Comment: I'll checkout those sources! Thanks. I'm used to pure js applications so Angular2 is very new.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. Please dismount from your high horse, and admit the truth, which is that A LOT is omitted from those tutorials, and they give a false sense of accomplishment. Worse yet, the whole ecosystem is in a constant state of flux. In only two days, I have had to upgrade a core component (zone.js) because the version that I installed on Monday was broken the next day by a an update of the Chrome Web browser.

Comment: There is no high horse, Angular docs are the best ever, really really good written and very complete, it's a pleasure to follow it. You probably had bad luck with zone.js . You need to go Quickstart -> Tutorial -> Guide -> Advanced -> CookBook